# I've got to display 1000+ uncategorized picture thumbnails on a mobile browser and I don't know how

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

Everything I try falls short when testing on a mobile. Loading times are unacceptably long, scrolling is jerky, etc. Thumbnails I'm working with are 120px wide. I understand this is not a specific question but I'd like to hear how would you approach this kind of problem?

Comment: I'd have between 10-20 images per page, then use AJAX to get the next/prev page as user requests.

Comment: Yeah, I'd work with paginated lists too. You'll be able to load faster 5 images than 1000. Then, I guess if you have 1000 images to display, 120px wide is a lot, right? Can't you add a mobile/light version? And finally, you can use the lazyLoad technique : only load what you have on the screen.

Comment: @SuperSkunk don't really want them smaller as I want this app to work on tablets and mobile phones alike without having have to make separate version of it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's what google images does on mobile and I think that's the only logical approach :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of three approaches

1. the classic way: use pagination, display only 10/20/50.. thumbnails per page
2. the modern (complex) way: add images when the user is scrolling, remove images from the DOM when they leave the visible area (best known example: the google picture search)
3. the clumsy way: splice the images together on the server, serve them as cluster of for example 3 x 5 thumbs

Comment: If i were the asker..i would go for the choice 2

Comment: Removing pictures from DOM doesn't remove them from memory. Need to replace 'src' attribute of a picture with a smaller (in size) picture to free the memory then remove it from DOM. Some browsers have got an arbitrary limit of total size of pictures that can be downloaded. 1000+ 120px wide pictures is about 20MB which is too much for safari mobile for instance. Also it quickly becomes very inefficient to work with 1000+ elements DOM.

Comment: Will go with the door number **one** :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to make all the thumbnails load at once. You can load 50 or hundred thumbnails when the page loads first and load remaining if they click on load more. Or you can organize them into pages

Loading at once makes your web page size more than an MB which will obviously take a lot of time to load